# Django SSLMiddleware issue on Webfaction

Tags: django, ssl, webfaction

I've been using the following SSLMiddleware on Linode for a while, and my SSL worked perfectly on that, now I've changed my server to Webfaction, and all of sudden, my HTTPS pages are not working in a way as it's redirected to https page correctly, but all my css files, images within the css files(no absolute url), javascript have all become non secure sources(referring to http:// instead of https://), I'm really puzzled right now as I don't know if it's got to do with SSLMiddleware or something else, I haven't changed anything in settings.py either apart from database parameter value.. Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
__license__ = "Python"
__copyright__ = "Copyright (C) 2007, Stephen Zabel"
__author__ = "Stephen Zabel - sjzabel@gmail.com"
__contributors__ = "Jay Parlar - parlar@gmail.com"

from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponsePermanentRedirect, get_host

SSL = 'SSL'

class SSLRedirect:

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        if SSL in view_kwargs:
            secure = view_kwargs[SSL]
            del view_kwargs[SSL]
        else:
            secure = False

        if settings.ENABLE_SSL:
                if not secure == self._is_secure(request):
                    return self._redirect(request, secure)
        else:
            return

    def _is_secure(self, request):
        if request.is_secure():
            return True

        #Handle the Webfaction case until this gets resolved in the request.is_secure()
        if 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL' in request.META:
            return request.META['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL'] == 'on'

        return False

    def _redirect(self, request, secure):
        protocol = secure and "https" or "http"
        newurl = "%s://%s%s" % (protocol,get_host(request),request.get_full_path())
        if settings.DEBUG and request.method == 'POST':
            raise RuntimeError, \
        """Django can't perform a SSL redirect while maintaining POST data.
           Please structure your views so that redirects only occur during GETs."""

        return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(newurl)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently implemented SSL on WebFaction without any custom Middleware tinkering and it was a very straightforward process.

Have a look here: http://community.webfaction.com/questions/512/how-do-i-set-up-a-https-ssl-django-site

If that doesn't help, open up a ticket with them. They're usually very good about resolving issues very quickly.

Comment: would this solution apply to partially secured web app? My app only has only few secured pages including login, settings, and these page url are not static depending on user.

Comment: Yes, you can choose which pages should be served securely and which can be left unsecured.